# Open Sans at Google Fonts turned it's normal font into bold

Tags: fonts, google-font-api

I was surprised why on different websites the font suddenly showed up bold and found out that for whatever reason the "Normal 400" font-style is now even bolder than "Bold 700" - take a look: http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans

Does anybody have an idea what I could do besides switching to another font? Didn't find a contact info for the font author (Steve Matteson if anybody happens to know him - https://profiles.google.com/107777320916704234605/about)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just discovered the same problem on my website and found an easy solution:
Check if you have installed the font locally and uninstall it.

I´ve found this help
[here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/googlefontdirectory-discuss/uA-fbVyaqRo)

Comment: Link is broken: "There is no group named “googlefontdirectory-discuss”